# Change Amount on Stripe Order

Tags: php, stripe-payments

The overall goal for me is to create discounts for one-time purchases, using the Stripe API. I noticed that discounts through the API is only for invoices, which i am not using for one-time payments.

What I am currently trying is to change the order amount. I read in the API that you cannot update the order amount, therefore I need to remove the existing order that is created through my code, and create a new one but with another amount than the original SKU item's price. This does not appear to work.

The request looks like this (through stripe dashboard log):

```
{
items:
 0:
  type: "sku"
  parent: "sku_8E8ZS8KYaJbUkK"
  quantity: "1"
  amount: "6800"
 1:
  type: "sku"
  parent: "sku_8E8I4F1FcseFQz"
  quantity: "2"
  amount: "6800"
  customer: cus_8TV6gRP0hrxmEy
  currency: "sek"
  metadata:
  delivery_date: "1463814000"
}
```

But the response seems to ignore my updated amount:

```
items: {
   object: "order_item"
   amount: 8500
   currency: "sek"
   description: "Specialpåse"
   parent: "sku_8E8ZS8KYaJbUkK"
   quantity: 1
   type: "sku"
}
```

PHP code:

```
$newOrder = \Stripe\Order::create(array(
                "items" => generateItems($items),
                "customer" => $customer,
                "currency" => "sek",
                "metadata" => array("delivery_date" => $delivery_date)
            ));

function generateItems($items) {
        $newArray = array();
        $x = 0;
        foreach ($items as $i) {
            $newArray[$x] = array("type" => $i['type'], "parent" => $i['parent'], "quantity" => $i['quantity'], "amount" => $i['product_price']*100);
            $x++;
        }
        return $newArray;
    }
```

Where $items looks something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => sku
            [parent] => sku_8E8ZS8KYaJbUkK
            [quantity] => 2
            [name] => Specialpåse
            [product_price] => 68
            [subscription_price] => 60
            [purchase_type] => single_purchase
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [type] => sku
            [parent] => sku_8E8I4F1FcseFQz
            [quantity] => 3
            [name] => Familjepåse
            [product_price] => 68
            [subscription_price] => 60
            [purchase_type] => single_purchase
        )

)
```

Comment: Is this not a direct question to Stripe support?

Comment: If I'm seeing this correctly, you can not *delete* an order, you can only **cancel** it by adding `status = canceled` to your request: https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to apply discounts to orders, by using the [`coupon`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_order-coupon) parameter in [order creation requests](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_order).

In PHP, it would look like this:

```
$newOrder = \Stripe\Order::create(array(
    "items" => generateItems($items),
    "customer" => $customer,
    "currency" => "sek",
    "metadata" => array("delivery_date" => $delivery_date),
    "coupon" => $couponId
));
```